# Exception propagates after already caught

Tags: spring, hibernate, flush

I'm having the strangest thing happening and I can't figure out why.  The best way to describe this is to provide a simplistic example:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Foo{
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("abc") Long id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        try {
            getDaoService().delete(id); //Calls Bar.delete()
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // Add a custom error message to the mav for the user to see
            mav.getModelMap().addAttribute(blah, blah);
        }
        return mav;
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class Bar {
    public void delete(final E entity) throws HibernateException {
        if (null != entity) {
            try {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
            } finally {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular case, I am trying to delete an object which has a constraint violation (ORA-02292). I expect the delete to fail because of this. When the delete fails, I wish to show the user an appropriate custom message.

Instead of being able to show the user a custom message, the call fails and displays the following to the screen:

> org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction 
>       rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

When I use a debugger, I can see that the error is appropriately caught and that the ModelAndView object has the custom message inside of it.  So, I have no clue why an exception is still being thrown after it has been caught and dealt with.  Does anyone have insight into why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the `@Transactional` annotation, you can state whether or not to roll back your transaction due to a given exception using the `noRollbackForClassName` attribute. You can do it similar to this.

```
@Service
@Transactional(noRollbackForClassName = "java.lang.Exception")
public class YourClass {
    ...
}
```

However, note that just saying `noRollbackForClassName = "java.lang.Exception"` would mean it will not rollback for any Exception (or its subclasses), hence its not a good practice.

What you should do is, figure out what exception is actually thrown first (may be by printing out the `e.getClass().getName()`), then set that class name as the noRollbackForClassName value.

Reason wise, this is happening because if some exception is thrown while attempting to delete(), the current transaction is automatically marked as roll back only, and if it is attempted to be committed, the exception you see will be thrown. The way to get passed this is to explicitly state that this certain exception should not cause a roll back.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because once an exception is thrown, Spring internally marks the tx as rollback-only.  This is completely separate from Java exception handling.  You have several options:

- Make sure your expected exception does not throw exceptions which extend `RuntimeException`; Spring only rolls back tx's when its a type `RuntimeException` ([see this page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), section 10.5.3).  [HibernateException extends RuntimeException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html), so that's why you're getting the rollback marker.
- Run each tx in its own transaction by moving the transactional method to its own class and annotating it using `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.  Then each call will run in its own tx and will not affect the overall tx.
- Use the `noRollbackForClassName` style venushka mentioned.  But use with caution, for the reason mentioned.

Comment: So what can I do when the exception extends RuntimeException?

Answer (score 1):

The Exception is being thrown in Bar#delete and is caught in Foo#delete. There is a @Transactional annotation on Bar#delete which is crossed before the exception is caught. This inner transaction is participating in the outer transaction and so the entire transaction is marked for rollback.

To avoid this you could remove the @Transactional annotation for Bar#delete. This method is already called within the scope of the other transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Add property **"globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure"** to the hibernateTransactionManager bean definition as follows.

```
<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
    **<property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="false" />**
</bean>
```